# How to disable login/password highlighting in Opera?

Tags: css, opera

Opera always orange highlights login/password inputs when user confirms "save password" prompt. It doesn't fit my design, is there any CSS way to alter/disable it?

**Edit** if not by CSS, is there any other solution?

Comment: My web page always disappears when the user closes their browser window. This doesn't fit my design; is there any way to alter/disable it?

Comment: @Cody Gray I think your comment is a little harsh, I can imagine that the orange highlight doesn't work well with some designs and another colour would be more suitable. I would argue as well that the visual aspect of the highlighting should be adjustable, and therefore can see the use of this question. IMHO

Comment: The only solution I have found is to change the login/password names randomly, but this disables the "remember password" feature. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foolproof JS solution. It just duplicates username and password fields (with changed name=""), hide original ones and set them id=username_original, ... When form_submit is triggered, values from new visible fields are copied to old fields (which are hidden, but have name attribute - Opera wand will handle these).

Additional CSS

```
.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", func, false);
}

function func() {
    // duplicate input[id=username], set to original class=hidden
    var obj = document.getElementById("username"); 
    var newObj = obj.cloneNode(true);
    newObj.name = "";     
    obj.id += "_original";  
    obj.className = "hidden";
    obj.parentNode.insertBefore(newObj,obj);   

    // duplicate input[id=password], set to original class=hidden                                       
    var obj = document.getElementById("password"); 
    var newObj = obj.cloneNode(true);
    newObj.name = "";      
    obj.id += "_original";    
    obj.className = "hidden";
    obj.parentNode.insertBefore(newObj,obj);  


    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = formSubmit;
}        

function formSubmit() {
    if(document.getElementById("username_original").value != "") return; 
    else if(document.getElementById("username_original").value != document.getElementById("username").value) {
        document.getElementById("username_original").value = document.getElementById("username").value;
        document.getElementById("password_original").value = document.getElementById("password").value;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

HTML form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form"><div>   
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</div></form>
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to disable this with CSS - it's a browser feature :-)

You also don't get far with trying out different border tweaks: outline affects the area around the highlight, inset box-shadow, background-color, etc. goes below it.

Comment: +1 Correct. You cannot use CSS to change or modify applications running on the user's computer. (Thank goodness.)

Comment: I don't think browser features can't be modified by CSS, ie: Chrome textareas are resizable unless "resize: none;" CSS property is applied on them. Look is not a browser feature: textboxes are different on every page, yet their behavior is the same: so changing the outline color is reasonable need - isn't it?

Comment: @janTuron: what Andreas is saying is that the modal window is not part of the Web site it is part of the browser chrome. So it is not accessible from the CSS and scripting context of the Web page.

Comment: The accepted solution worked for me in Opera. You all were correct, but the point is: there IS a way. It is just the way you had not considered. Therefore it is better to say "I don't know" rather than "it's not possible".